# Moving indices in an array

Tags: java, arrays, shift

I am trying to write a write a program that receives an `String[]` and prints out the array with the first string alphabetically first. I have to use three methods like these. Here is a sample input/output:

```
bob, joe, aaron, zack   ----> aaron, bob, joe, zack
```

- `findFirstName()` is correctly finding the first `String` alphabetically and returning its location.
- `MoveToRightOne` is correctly shifting each `String` right one while overwriting the first string alphabetically and repeating the first one (ex: `bob bob joe zack`).
- `moveName()` is not working correctly. It is supposed to replace the first instance of "bob" with "aaron" but is usually off by one or two places.

Does anyone see why this might be happening in `moveOne()`?

```
public static String [] moveName(String [] names) {
    String names1 [] = names.clone();   
    int firstPosition = findFirstName(names1);
    String[] NewNames = moveToRightOne(names1, firstPosition, firstPosition+1);
    String firstAlph=  names1 [firstPosition];
    System.out.println(names1 [firstPosition]);
    NewNames [0] = firstAlph;

    return NewNames;
}
```

---

```
public static int findFirstName(String[ ] names1 ) {
    // receives an array of Strings, and returns the location (i.e. index) of the first
    // name (alphabetically)

    String first=names1[0];
    int firstPosition = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<names1.length; i++) {
        int result =names1[i].compareToIgnoreCase(first);

        if (result < 0) {
            first= names1[i];
            firstPosition = i;
        }
    }

    return firstPosition;
}
```

---

```
public static String[] moveToRightOne (String[] names, int startSpot,  int  endSpot) {
    for (int i = (startSpot - 1); i >= 0; i--) {                
        names[i+1] = names[i];
    }

    return names;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example where you actually call the code and get incorrect results. As written, your code is taking parameters and your prose is describing values, so it is a little difficult to follow.

Comment: For example, if I enter bob, joe, aaron, zack, it returns joe, bob, joe, zack.

Comment: Please also include the desired output for clarity.

Comment: The desired output is aaron, bob, joe, zack.

Comment: You store off the *position* of the first name, the shift the array, invalidating that position.  Store the actual name instead.

Comment: @merlin2011 The desired output is in the part _sample input/output_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moveToRightOne` does not make a copy of the `names` array that you pass in.  Instead, it modifies it directly.  That means when you say

```
String[] NewNames = moveToRightOne(names1, firstPosition, firstPosition+1);
```

the strings will be shifted in `names1`, and after that, `NewNames` and `names1` will just be references to the same array.  I think your intent is to make `NewNames` be an array with the strings shifted, and leave `names1` alone, but that isn't what's happening.  That means that the following statement is going to return the wrong string:

```
String firstAlph=  names1 [firstPosition];
```

(Or, since `names1` is already a clone of `names`, maybe what you want is to use `names` instead of `names1` when trying to access elements from the not-yet-shifted array.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `moveToRightOne` function was broken, so you were not actually using all the parameters passed in. Also, you should grab the first name alphabetically before you actually overwrite it using that function.

```
public class Shift {
    public static void moveName(String [] names) {
        int firstPosition = findFirstName(names);

        // Store the name at that position
        String firstName = names[firstPosition];
        moveToRightOne(names, 0, firstPosition);
        names [0] = firstName;
    }
    public static int findFirstName(String[] names1) {
        // receives an array of Strings, and returns the location (i.e. index)
        // of the first name (alphabetically)

        String first=names1[0];
        int firstPosition = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<names1.length; i++) {
            int result =names1[i].compareToIgnoreCase(first);

            if (result < 0) {
                first= names1[i];
                firstPosition = i;
            }
        }

        return firstPosition;
    }
    public static void moveToRightOne (String[] names, int startSpot,  int  endSpot) {
        for (int i = (endSpot - 1); i >= startSpot; i--) {                
            names[i+1] = names[i];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String[] original = new String[] { "bob", "joe", "aaron", "zac"};
        for (String s: original) System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println();
        moveName(original);
        for (String s: original) System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Arrays.sort() for sorting instead.This is not exact solution for the problem, but an alternate way for it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test{
Public static void main(String args[]){
  String str[]= {'Mike','Adam','Peter','Brian'};
  System.out.println("str"+str[0]); // Mike
  Arrays.sort(str);
  System.out.println("str"+str[0]); //Adam
  }  
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding some additional explanation on your answer.  The OA spent time writing their question.  Maybe you can clarify and expand on your response?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `moveToRightOne` is correct? (if `firstPosition` is `0` you will get no changes as the `for` loop will not execute)

Just a quick Thought:

If you are looking do a sort manually (I assume this is for a class). I will also assume you are trying to implement **insertion sort** algorithm (otherwise Arrays.sort() is your friend). The way you are approaching it, it looks like you will be making multiple passes through the array to achieve a sort. if you want to do that switch to **bubble sort** instead.

The description of the **insertion sort** code will look something like this:

Start looping through your array, compare that the element at **index** is greater than element at **index + 1**. if not true move to the next element. if true compare the smaller element (call it **A**) to all previous elements until it is greater than the next previous element (lets call it **B**). Save a copy of **A** Shift all elements after **B** to the right (by 1) until you get to the **A**'s old position . insert the copy of **A** into position just after **B**. Continue from the old **A**'s index. Rinse/repeat until the end of the array

you may want to simplify your code in that case (and always check for edge conditions like `0` and `Array.length`)

HTH